# Error in Vite Preview : Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite

I am facing this `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined` error when using `vite preview` after `vite build`.

[image]

My `vite.config.js` looks something like below.

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import {NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin} from '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill';
// ...
export default defineConfig({
  // ...
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
    emptyOutDir: false
  },
  server: {
    host: true
  },
  define: {
    'process.env': {}
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      // Node.js global to browser globalThis
      define: {
        global: 'globalThis'
      },
      // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
      plugins: [
        NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
          buffer: true
        })
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

I am not facing this error when using `npm start`. Could someone please help me in this situation.
[image]

Comment: it'd help to know which line of your code throws that error - oh, is it an error in the browser or on the cli?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add the Error Statement, I am facing "process is not defined" on the browser.

Comment: maybe one of your dependencies is using process.env 
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1973
it would be great to see the actual code

Comment: Any progress @YashChauhan?

Answer (score 2):

[env variables VITE DOCS](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html)

In your .env file define the variables starting with 'VITE_'.

To read the variable use 'import.meta.env.'

Example:

```js
VITE_SOME_KEY='examplekey'

const READ_KEY = import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY;
```

Try using that in your vite config file: [CONFIG Environment Variables](https://vitejs.dev/config/#environment-variables) Replacing the .env with the import.meta.env